# apache how to set timeout on single file on vhost

Tags: apache

timeout=30 is normally for example. When I change this to 300 (5 minutes) I can get my script to finish but I do not want to allow all pages/scripts to wait for 5 minutes. How can I apply a timeout value to a single file on a vhost? Can I use filesmatch or directory directives?

Answer (score 8):

Just add timeout=300 in yor vhost

```
<VirtualHost myserver:80>
TimeOut 300
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout